# What is the meaning of functional API in keras?

Tags: keras

When I read the Keras document I find a term called functional API.

What is the meaning of functional API in Keras?

Could anyone help you to understand the basic and significant terms in Keras?

Thanks

Comment: I work with Keras for 3 years now but never once see that term outside https://keras.io so it's probably not as significant as you think

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen I see it used fairly regularly here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I actually just mange to summarize what it means after I saw this question lol

Answer (score 0):

It is a way to create your models. One can use sequential models (tutorial [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/)):

For example:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(784,)),
    Activation('relu'),
    Dense(10),
    Activation('softmax'),
])
```

And you can call it with input features. Second approach is functional (tutorial [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/)). You call each layer with the next which allows you to have more flexibility when creating your model, for example:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

# This returns a tensor
inputs = Input(shape=(784,))

# a layer instance is callable on a tensor, and returns a tensor
output_1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
# you call layer with another layer to create model
output_2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(output_1)
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(output_2)

# This creates a model that includes
# the Input layer and three Dense layers
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(data, labels)  # starts training
```

You could also subclass `Model`, similar to what Chainer or PyTorch provide to the user, but it's used that heavily in Keras.